# Cisco VTP message ((lowest numbered VLAN interface found)

Tags: cisco, vtp

I have vtp server 6500 and vtp clients N5K all its working fine, except this message (lowest numbered VLAN interface found)..
I dont really know if I have to take care on this message I mean its an error message that I have to debug or its a normal message ?

Thanks for your help
Here below the example:
[image]

Comment: Please copy the exact message, in context, from your terminal and paste it into your question.

Comment: Make sure your VTP passwords are the same across all devices.

Comment: The password are same since the DB is updated I have only this message at the end of the ((show vtp status)) on the vtp server side, see the printscreen.

Comment: @RonMaupin please see the print screen I added

Comment: That is not an error. Do a search for `cisco vtp local updater`. That is the switch that last updated the VTP database. The current best practice is to not use VTP.

Comment: @ronmaupin I'd argue that VTP v3 fixes the problems with earlier versions and is therefore a viable feature.  Of course, if you really  need VTP, you probably have excessively large L2 domains, so there is that.

Comment: Thanks Ron Maupin, what you mean not use VTP ? you mean use VTP transparent ? I though we cannot by pass to not use VTP?

Comment: @RonTrunk I understood that this is not a problem ?

Comment: If you have multiple IP addresses on your VTP server, the Local updater will use the first IP address found on your switch/router. If you utilize `sh ip int brief`you will see the first interface VLAN 7 has the IP address 155.1.7.7.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple IP addresses on your VTP server, the Local updater will use the first IP address found on your switch/router. If you utilize `sh ip int brief` you will see the first interface VLAN 7 has the IP address 155.1.7.7.

If you remove the interface or IP address the local updater will use the next interface in line.